# How (and why) should a JUL configuration class be initialized?

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

I have a command line tool (`frontend.java`) using an args4j options class (`Options.java`) and a JUL configuration class (`LogConfig.java`). Because in my actual application I need to see and use the selected options in order to configure logging, I have a static getter in `frontend` that returns the various args4j options that have been selected by the user.

```
frontend.java:
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class frontend{
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(frontend.class.getName());
    private static Options opts = new Options();

    public frontend(){
        System.out.println("Made a new front end");
    }
    public static Options getOptions(){
        if(opts == null)
            System.out.println("Opts was null");
        else
            System.out.println("Opts is not null");
        return opts;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frontend fe = new frontend();
    }
}
```

Obviously, this next file isn't really blank but I'm not sure that I need anything in here to show what my problem is.

```
Options.java:
public class Options{
}
```

And finally, the configuration class:

```
LogConfig.java:
import java.util.logging.LogManager;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

public class LogConfig {
    public LogConfig() {
        Options opts = frontend.getOptions();
        try {
            LogManager.getLogManager().readConfiguration(new FileInputStream("logging.properties"));
        }catch (SecurityException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem accessing log config file: "
                               + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Problem loading log config file: "
                               + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that the `LogConfig` class seems to get a hold of the `opts` variable before it's been set by the static initialization:

```
Output:
c:\>java -cp . frontend
Made a new front end
Opts is not null

c:\>java -Djava.util.logging.config.class=LogConfig -cp . frontend
Opts was null
Made a new front end
Opts is not null

c:\>
```

What is the best approach to using the JUL log configuration class when your main class has to be somewhat alive before you know what your configuration class needs to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating of the Logger triggers the LogManager startup.  Delay the creation of your logger until you need to use it.

```
public class frontend {

    private static volatile Logger log;
    private static Options opts = new Options();

    public frontend() {
        System.out.println("Made a new front end");
    }

    public static Options getOptions() {
        if (opts == null) {
            System.out.println("Opts was null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Opts is not null");
        }
        return opts;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frontend fe = new frontend();
        log = Logger.getLogger(frontend.class.getName());
    }
}
```

Otherwise you can simply recreate the config class yourself after the LogManager startup is complete.  Then make your LogConfig perform a no-op when the getOptions returns null.

```
public class frontend {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(frontend.class.getName());
    private static Options opts = new Options();

    public frontend() {
        System.out.println("Made a new front end");
    }

    public static Options getOptions() {
        if (opts == null) {
            System.out.println("Opts was null");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Opts is not null");
        }
        return opts;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        frontend fe = new frontend();
        init();
    }

    private static void init() {
        String n = System.getProperty("java.util.logging.config.class");
        if (n != null) {
            try { //LogManager uses the system class loader.
                Class<?> k = Class.forName(n, false,
                        ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
                k.newInstance();
            } catch (ReflectiveOperationException | LinkageError ignore) {
                ignore.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's actually what I did - namely, to put the log configuration in the initialization of `frontend`.  It seems to me that in many cases this is sort of obviates the notion of java.util.logging.config.class as well as the global "config" property. What you have here (and what I did) seems to me to be bypassing the "free" configuration processing. Rather than using either the OOTB "java.util.logging.config.class" mechanism or the introspection, I just did what amounts to LogConfig.configure(). I guess the gotcha is that the configuration class cannot be privy to the frontend class.